# Are there limitations in using DNase I hypersensitive sites (DHSs) to identify candidate enhancers?

Tags: genetics, dna, genomics, gene-regulation, chromatin

Candidate enhancer regions are often defined in studies by DHSs and/or certain chromatin marks. I was wondering if DHSs are exhaustive for identifying possible enhancer regions, and if there is any work out there demonstrating enhancer regions in areas not sensitive to DNase 1.